# Compound switch cases: may we have a single common value binding for compound enum cases that have the same type of associated value?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

*(As I prepared and almost finished writing up the question, re-reading the appropriate language guide section answered it for me, but possibly the Q&A can be of use for others, so I'll post it nonetheless)*

**Background**

Consider the following `enum`, with cases that have one of two different types of associated values, `Int` or `String`:

```
enum Foo {
    case bar(Int)
    case baz(Int)
    case bax(Int)
    case fox(String)
}
```

When performing pattern matching in a `switch` statement, we may construct compound cases, each covering several possible matching patterns (entering the `case` branch if any of the patterns match):

```
func foo(_ foo: Foo) -> Int {
    switch foo {
        case .bar, .baz, .bax: return 42
        case .fox: return 0
    }
}
```

Just like non-compound cases, compound cases may also include value binding:

```
func foo(_ foo: Foo) -> Int {
    switch foo {
        case .bar(let x), .baz(let x), .bax(let x): return x 
        case .fox(let y): return Int(y) ?? 0
    }
}

// or
func foo(_ foo: Foo) -> Int {
    switch foo {
        case let .bar(x), let .baz(x), let .bax(x): return x 
        case let .fox(y): return Int(y) ?? 0
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- Is it possible to use a single common value binding for compound cases, which covers the compound of several `enum` cases that have the same type of associated value?

E.g., in the latter value binding examples above, some way to use a single binding functionality for the common-type associated value in the compound `case`

```
// not valid
func foo(_ foo: Foo) -> Int {
    switch foo {
        case .bar, .baz, .bax, (let x): return x 
        case .fox: return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible; in the value binding examples above, `x` must be bound in every pattern, and this must hold separately for every pattern in the compound cases.

Quoting the [Language Guide - Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) [**emphasis mine**]

> Compound cases can also include value bindings. All of the patterns of
>   a compound case **have to include the same set of value bindings**, and
>   each binding **has to get a value of the same type from all of the
>   patterns in the compound case**. This ensures that, **no matter which part
>   of the compound case matched, the code in the body of the case can
>   always access a value for the bindings** and that the value always has
>   the same type.

I we try to omit the binding in one of the patterns in the compound example above, we are given quite an self-explanatory error message on the subject:

```
func foo(_ foo: Foo) -> Int {
    switch foo {
        case .bar(_), .baz(let x), .bax(let x): return x 
        case .fox: return 0
    }
}
```

> ```
> error: 'x' must be bound in every pattern
> ```

This holds even if we don't use `x` in the body that follows

```
func foo(_ foo: Foo) -> Int {
    switch foo {
        case .bar(_), .baz(let x), .bax(let x): return 0 
        case .fox: return 0
    }
} // same error
```