# Is it possible to write compound switch case between enum associated value conditional and another enum case?

Tags: swift, enums

For demo purposes I've created next code:

```swift
enum WeatherType {
    case cloudy(coverage: Int)
    case sunny
    case rainy
}

let today: WeatherType = .cloudy(coverage: 0)

switch today {
case .cloudy(let coverage) where coverage == 0, .sunny:   // <-- This line doesn't compile
    print("☀️")
case .cloudy(let coverage) where 1...100 ~= coverage:
    print("☁️")
case .rainy:
    print("")
default:
    print("Unknown weather")
}
```

The compile error message is `'coverage' must be bound in every pattern`. As I've already googled that a way to go with associated values is to compare different states of values within the same enum case. But this may lead to code duplication, like in my example, where I need to write two case statements for `.sunny` and `.cloudy(let coverage) where coverage == 0`.

Is there any correct, swifty way, to deal with such cases?

Comment: Cloudly with coverage 0 should be invalid in your data model. Once it becomes an illegal value, you won't have to worry about handling it all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this is code created for demo purposes only, just to find out about switch/case capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a where-clause to match `.cloudy(coverage: 0)`, just

```
case .cloudy(coverage: 0), .sunny: 
    print("☀️")
```

Another option is to use `fallthrough`, for example

```
case .cloudy(let coverage) where coverage < 10:
    fallthrough
case .sunny:
    print("☀️")
```

Comment: Somewhat related to this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41251872/4573247

Answer (score 3):

Martin is right (+1).

But I might suggest a further refinement, moving your `switch` into an an extension of `WeatherType` (which I’d probably just call `Weather`) so that you don’t have to repeat this `switch` statement every time you’re looking for the symbol:

```
enum Weather {
    case cloudy(Int)
    case sunny
    case rainy
}

extension Weather {
    var symbol: String {
        switch self {
        case .cloudy(0), .sunny:
            return "☀️"
        case .cloudy:
            return "☁️"
        case .rainy:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let today: Weather = .cloudy(0)
print(today.symbol)
```

And even if you wanted to consider anything less than 10 as sunny, you still don’t need `where` clause:

```
extension Weather {
    var symbol: String {
        switch self {
        case .cloudy(..<10), .sunny:
            return "☀️"
        case .cloudy:
            return "☁️"
        case .rainy:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One can even use partial ranges: `case .cloudy(..<10)`

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing the ideas about extension and the ranges shorthand syntax!

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matches are composable, so you can do this:

```
switch today {
case .sunny, .cloudy(0):
    print("☀️")
case .cloudy(1...10):
    print("☁️")
case .rainy:
    print("")
default:
    print("Unknown weather")
}
```

Comment: `case .cloudy(1...10):` without where – that is better!

Comment: @MartinR Still not perfect. `.cloudy(0)` should be an illegal state, otherwise it'll pop up all over the app logic. I would make a struct wrapper that exposes an initializer that ensures `.sunny` is used instead of `.cloudy(0)`